# How to check if variable is a code object in python

Tags: python

I have this code -

```
code_obj = compile("k=1", "<string>", "exec")
```

How can I check if the variable is a code object by type comparison or using isinstance.

Comment: https://www.journaldev.com/22772/python-compile-function

Comment: use `type` function

Comment: the normal way, `isinstance(some_object, code)` where code is the code class, e.g. `code = type(compile('','','exec'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer by @blhsing works fine, but in case you don't want to import anything new, the following does the exact same.

```py
code_obj = compile("k=1", "<string>", "exec")
code_class = type(compile("", "<string>", "exec"))
if isinstance(code_obj, code_class):
    print("code_obj is a code object")
```

To be really sure they do the same thing,

```py
>>> import types
>>> code_class = type(compile("", "<string>", "exec"))
>>> print(types.CodeType, code_class)
True
```

So you can use either `types.CodeType` or `type(compile(...))` as a parameter to `isinstance(...)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can check if an object is an instance of `types.CodeType`:

```
import types
code_obj = compile("k=1", "<string>", "exec")
if isinstance(code_obj, types.CodeType):
    print('code_obj is a code object')
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/bveBX3

Answer (score 0):

`inspect.iscode` returns `True` for code objects.

```
inspect.iscode((lambda: 0).__code__)
```